# Complex subfields of finite index

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

It is known that the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers is a complex subfield of index 2, that is, $[\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}]=2$. Given an integer $n>2$ fixed, does there exist a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ of index $n$?

Comment: Nice question, especially if you don't know the answer.  Even to show there are no proper fields of finite index of $\mathbb{R}$ seems like a good exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such subfield.  It is a theorem of Artin-Schreier that if $K$ is algebraically closed and $L$ is a proper subfield of $K$ such that $[K:L]<\infty$, then $K$ is obtained from $L$ by adding a square root of $-1$, so $[K:L]=2$.  See [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8759/39640).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.