# Degree of irreducible polynomial

Tags: field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be algebraic closure of field $\mathbb{k}$ and $[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{k}] = n < \infty$. I have proved that if $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{k}$ than $\deg f | n$. But if $d | n$ is there irreducible polynomial of degree $d$? In zero characteristic?

Comment: If an algebraic closure is of finite degree, then [this degree is at most $2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1586074/110831).  With this information, the question becomes somewhat trivial.